# Check if table contains entries with same id and compare the values of these entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the columns `FileID`, `State` and `Date`
It contains every action, which is be done with the file
For example if I create a file, it inserts an entry with a new FileId, the date, when it was created and the state "created". And if I delete this file, it creates a new entry with the fileId of the file, sets the date, when it was deleted and sets the state "deleted"
So it would look like this

```
FileID | Date     | State
----------------------------
FileA  | 1.1.2016 | Created
FileA  | 3.1.2016 | Deleted
FileB  | 1.1.2016 | Created
```

What I want is to get all files, which existed at a certain date. So if I say, I want all files, which existed at 2.1.2016 it should return the first row of File A and FileB in my example. If I am looking for all files at 4.1.2016 it should return the row with FileB

How do I do this comparison?
I was trying something like

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA
WHERE FileId IN     (SELECT FileId FROM TableA WHERE Date <= [DATE] AND State = 'Created')
  AND FileId NOT IN (SELECT FileId FROM TableA WHERE Date > [DATE] AND State = 'Deleted')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
WHERE Date >= [DATE] AND State = 'Created' AND FileId NOT IN (SELECT FileId FROM TableA WHERE Date >= [DATE] AND State = 'Deleted')
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach but this one is getting the same result as my approach. I don't get any results, if I try it this way

Comment: @Echelon Can u build sql fiddle for this?

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2012+ you need to group by FileID and then use window functions to get the newest state:

```
select FileID, 
    first_value(State) over (partition by FileID order by Date desc) as LastAction
from TableA
where Date <= [DATE]
group by FileID
having first_value(State) over (partition by FileID order by Date desc) <> 'Deleted'
```

SQL Server 2008 does not support `first_value()` and you'll need to use `row_number()` in a subquery to work around this:

```
select FileID
from (
    select FileID,
        State,
        row_number() over (partition by FileID order by Date desc) as LastActionRow
    from TableA
    where Date <= [DATE]
)
where LastActionRow = 1
  and State <> 'Deleted'
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Well, yes, the first_value() only appeared in 2012. I'll update with a workaround

Answer (score 0):

In the query below, we first select records that were created before the given date.  Then join back to the same table looking for when the files were deleted before the given date.

The left join for the deleted records will return NULL if the file has not been deleted.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a

-- Join to TableA, looking for 'Deleted' records before the requested date
LEFT JOIN TableA b ON 
    a.FileID = b.FileID AND b.state = 'Deleted' AND b.Date <= [Date]

WHERE
    -- Find files that were created before the requested date
    a.State = 'Created'
    AND a.Date <= [DATE]
    -- and have not been deleted before the requested date
    AND b.FileID IS NULL
```

*Note that this assumes that you only have one "created" and one "deleted" record for each fileID.*

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT A.* from TableA A
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT FileID, MIN([Date]) minDate FROM TableA GROUP BY FileID ) TM
ON A.FileID= TM.FileID and A.Date = TM.minDate
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for all your suggestions, but I came up with a solution by myself now, which at least works in my situation.

The solution is:

```
Select * FROM TableA
WHERE State = 'Created' AND Date <= [DATE]
AND FileId NOT IN (SELECT FileID FROM TableA WHERE State = 'Deleted' AND Date <= [DATE])
```